# How to convert timestamp to date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyyHo.jpg

I have a dataset as shown in the image. I want to use the values of created_date column as `datetime` format. How can i do that?

Comment: Clarify If the image is the data in the database or if it is the data in a .NET Dataset/DataTable.   Can you give the data type that is defined for the column called created_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column values does not seems to be a TimeStamp.
Use the below script to make the values as datetime .

```
    SELECT credits,amount,city,
                  CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(created_date,8)
                  +' '+SUBSTRING(created_date,9,2)
                  +':'+SUBSTRING(created_date,11,2)
                  +':'+RIGHT(created_date,2)) Created_Date
    FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Abhinav Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 4):

The time you would like to convert is called `Unix timestamp`, which means how many seconds have passed since 1970/01/01. In this occasion you will have to use `DATA` function, which will take the total number of seconds and add them to 1970/01/01.

In SQL it is done in the following way:

```
select DATEADD(s, dateTimeInSeconds, '19700101')
```

Where `s` is Seconds and dateTimeInSeconds is your value of date; `'19700101'` is a starting point.

Comment: You sure it isn't the date time without any delimiters?

Answer (score 0):

Is created_date of type 'epoch'? And are you trying to use the datetime format within the SQL database or within your business logic? If it is in the business logic, it then depends on the language you use. I'd love to help but I don't fully understand the use case. If you could provide more information that would help us help you!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like unix timestamp but datetime without some chars (just digits are left).

To get "real" timestamp use in MySql: unix_timestamp()

To convert "real" timestamp to datetime use in MySql: FROM_UNIXTIME()

To convert your column to datetime use:

```
    CONCAT(SUBSTR(created_date, 1, 4),
        '-',
        SUBSTR(created_date, 5, 2),
        '-',
        SUBSTR(created_date, 6, 2),
        ' ',
        SUBSTR(created_date, 7, 2),
        ':',
        SUBSTR(created_date, 11, 2),
        ':',
        SUBSTR(created_date, 13, 2))
```

Comment: Question was tagged as SQL Server not MYSQL just a heads up